# Repository and Task input filepath

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there a way to clear an input field in a task every-time the source directory/repository is changed?

Context:I am developing a custom VSTS task, and in it I have a input field type filepath.

I would like to clear the input field in my task every time the user changes the GetSource or Repository.

Existing behavior in "Copy Files to:" task:

eg: Consider in Get sources -->select a source I have selected GitHub, and a repository out of my account.

In the "Copy Files to: " task , input field "Source Folder" I go ahead and select a folder from my Repo (Browse Source Folder--> Select path).

If I return to the GetSource and change the "repository" or "selected source", then this input field in the "Copy Files to: " task is not relevant anymore. But it remains the same. I have to manually clear the field.

I would like to have this cleared automatically.

Is there a way we can accomplish this?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [azure pipelines tasks samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) and the [task schema](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/tasks.schema.json) but did not find such a way. If you would like that feature, you can [create a request for this feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) in developer community.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.